# Will there be a 10th US democratic primary debate?

Tags: united-states, hillary-clinton, bernie-sanders, democratic-party, democratic-primary

There is an open slot on [democrats.org](https://www.democrats.org/more/the-2016-primary-debate-schedule) for a 10th debate in May, but the location and date are still TBD. Is this debate likely to take place?

Comment: You're asking whether a future event will take place. The answer can only be "we don't know" until it happens. A better question would be whether it is *planned* to take place. In which case the answer could probably still be "we don't know".

Comment: @PointlessSpike The original post asked if it is "likely to take place", but it was edited. I have edited it back now. I guess one way to determine if it might happen is  to know if it has been common in previous primaries to not host debates this late in the primary or when one candidate is leading by a certain margin at a certain point. My concern is that the DNC considers the race "over" and sees no point in doing another debate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. [The debate never happened.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_Party_presidential_debates_and_forums,_2016)